# Rails code in model behaves differently development vs production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ... 

  def gen_filename(type)
    @tmp = self.filename
    while @tmp.include? "%type%"
       @tmp.sub! "%type%", type
    end
    @tmp
  end

end
```

views/products/list.hml.haml containts this code:

```
= product.filename
%br
- @filename=product.gen_filename( "xxx" )
= product.filename
```

The output in development is:

```
%type%.txt 
%type%.txt
```

The output in production is:

```
%type%.txt 
xxx.txt
```

Could anyone explain what i am doing wrong ?

( i have simplified the code by hand, hope i did not made a bug )

: Edit

So this works in development en production mode the same way:

```
  def gen_filename(type)
    @tmp = self.filename

    if !@tmp.nil?
      @tmp = @tmp.gsub("%type%", type)    
    end
    @tmp
  end
```

And this does not behave the same way

```
  def gen_filename(type)
    @tmp = self.filename

    if !@tmp.nil?
      while @tmp.include? "%type%"
         @tmp.sub! "%type%", type
      end
    end
    @tmp
  end
```

I find this strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is unnecessary.

```
def gen_filename(type)
  @tmp = self.filename.gsub("%type%", type)
end
```

If you still have problems, post the **actual** code surrounding the problem instead of a simplified version.

Comment: Deefour, thanks for you quick response. But this does not help me, because your improvement still gives me the same result. In development product.filename is not changed in production it is changed.

Comment: @me1960 thats why I'm asking for the **actual** code and not some oversimplified version of it you presented above.

Comment: me again... ;-) I have just looked into the problem again... You are never to old to learn.. My mistake, the improvement does work, but i still am not clear why my code using sub give a different behaviour between production and development mode. I edit the question.